# Get result of spawning child process in Node.js

Tags: node.js, child-process, reason, bucklescript

How do I execute a child process and get the resulting exit code and output (stdout, stderr)?

Something like

```
let spawnResult = Node.Child_process.spawnSync("ls");

Js.log("Exit code: " ++ spawnResult.status);

Js.log("Stdout: " ++ spawnResult.stdout);

Js.log("Stderr: " ++ spawnResult.stderr);
```

Unfortunately this results in a compile error:

```
Unbound record field status
```

Comment: You can use native node with reason? What is `Node.Child_process`

Comment: @dzm it's node.js bindings via bucklescript https://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/api/Node_child_process.html

I can do Js.log(spawnResult) and it does in fact print a record or some structure:

`    { status: 0,
      signal: null,
      output:
       [ null,
         <Buffer hex series removed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1. `spawnResult` is actually an abstract type, and will have to be cast to a Js Object using `Node.Child_process.readAs` before being used.
2. JavaScript Object fields are accessed using the `##`operator. `.` is reserved for accessing record fields (and `#` is for plain OCaml objects).

In addition, `++` will only concatenate strings, while `status` is an `int`, and `stdout` and `stderr` are `string_buffer`s. You therefore need to either use string interpolation, which converts to `string` automatically, manually convert them before concatenating, or use `Js.log2`:

Using string interpolation:

```
let status = Node.Child_process.readAs(spawnResult)##status;
Js.log({j|Exit code: $status|j});
```

Using manual string conversion

```
Js.log("Exit code: " ++ string_of_int(Node.Child_process.readAs(spawnResult)##status));
```

Using `Js.log2`:

```
Js.log2("Exit code: ", Node.Child_process.readAs(spawnResult)##status);
```